# Tensorflow.js - My model works as expected if it was trained on CPU but does not work when trained on GPU

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, google-colaboratory, tensorflow.js

I made a model in Google Colab based on Pix2Pix. I downloaded it so that I can display it on a website with Tensorflow.js. I can get the model to behave as expected if I trained it on CPU, but the output of the model is just NaN if it was trained on GPU. Specifically, the output image of the CPU-trained model has color and the output image of the GPU-trained model is all black.

Both models are trained for only 2 steps while I prove out the concept. I don't want to wait for the CPU training.

[Top: The input satellite image. Middle: The output image if the model was trained on CPU. It is colored as expected. Bottom: The output image if the model was trained on GPU. It is all black.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQUC6.png)

[Link to Google Colab Notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/13UkkX4txs-9_c9vswORxs5gS5S7erxws?usp=sharing)

[Link to Sample Repo](https://github.com/Moses-Ian/question-repo)

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this?

I tried a few different runtimes when training the model, but the only one that works is CPU.

I tried setting the backend to both CPU and WebGL, but nothing changed.

I updated my graphic drivers.